# Creativity Linked List with value

Tags: c

Creativity problem linked list
I try to put into one cell a list of lists within which there are words
But when I want to vote for the next organ I come across an anomaly

the compiler said:

Exception thrown: read access violation.
list->next was nullptr

in this line "list = list->next->data;"

```
LinkedList* getWordSuggestions(HashTable* dictionaryTable, char* word) {
    LinkedList* list = NULL;
    list = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));

    if (word == NULL)
        return list;
    list = replaceCharacterCheck(dictionaryTable, word);
    list = list->next->data;
    list = addSpaceCheck(dictionaryTable, word);
    list = list->next->data;
    list = deleteCharacterCheck(dictionaryTable, word);
    list = list->next->data;
    list = addCharacterCheck(dictionaryTable, word);
    list = list->next->data;
    list = switchAdjacentCharacterCheck(dictionaryTable, word);
    return list;
}
```

linklist.h:

```
typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList;

struct LinkedList {
    char* data;
    LinkedList* next;
};

void PrintList(LinkedList*);
LinkedList* BuildNode(char*);
LinkedList* addToStart(LinkedList*, char*);
LinkedList* addToEND(LinkedList*, char*);
LinkedList* FreeList(LinkedList*);
LinkedList* DeleteElement(LinkedList*, char*);
int isInList(LinkedList*, char*);
```

all this function is working perfect

```
LinkedList* BuildNode(char*);

LinkedList* addToStart(LinkedList*, char*);

LinkedList* addToEND(LinkedList*, char*);

LinkedList* FreeList(LinkedList*);

LinkedList* DeleteElement(LinkedList*, char*);
```

Comment: Voting for the next organ usually mediates a heap rather than a linked list.

Comment: To detect invalid pointer access, 1. define a macro for access and 2. logging macros.
If you want to prevent allocation bugs (leaking or use after free), use at least valgrind or overload malloc with macros to implement you allocation logging for debugging.

Comment: Your problem is that `list = list->next->data;` unconditionally accesses next, but `next` might be nullptr.
You also dont check, if the allocation succeeded.
You question does not contain checkable code, as you only provide the interface.